# creating a csv file from svg paths and ids

Tags: python, csv, svg

I have an SVG file with id and coordinates . How to extract the id and coordinates into their own key-value pairs? So there are hundreds similar to the path below. I've tried using `re.findall` to separate the values but can't push them into arrays/dicts.

```
<path
id="58"
d="
M 457984.36 7575754.89
L 468060.3 7580832.86
L 520309.28 7583741.78
L 553166.03 7596446.73
L 555605.05 7594867.37
L 561992.47 7597226.43
z" />
```

Comment: Could you provide the expected output?

Comment: *"can't push them into arrays/dicts"* - what exactly do you mean by this? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these purposes I removed the line returns in your example.

```
import re

data = '<path id="58" d="M 457984.36 7575754.89 L 468060.3 7580832.86 L 520309.28 7583741.78 L 553166.03 7596446.73 L 555605.05 7594867.37 L 561992.47 7597226.43 z" />

all_coords = re.findall('id="([0-9]{1,4})" d="((?:[ML] [0-9]{6,8}\.[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{6,8}\.[0-9]{1,2}).+?)\s."', data)

coordDict = dict(all_coords)
```

Essentially I used a group capture to create a tuple from the value of the 'id' and 'd' attrs. I tested this with multipule path tags.

To complete the csv output you can do

```
import csv

with open("test.csv", "wb") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows((k, v) for k, v in coordDict.iteritems())
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. What if the case was that instead of an "id" we would have "class= posta-num-879". Also within the class ag there are several others (postal-name, postal-region etc)?

Comment: Modify the regex to match the patterns you expect to show up and repeat. Something along the lines of: re.findall('class="(postal-[a-z]{3,6})"